# Property is not supported in LINQ-to-entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, iqueryable

I'm having a problem and I don't know how to solve it. I already watched millions of posts like this but doesn't help me.

I have this:

```
public interface IInterface
{
    int Order { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AbstractClass { }
```

and two implementations

```
public class FirstImplementation : AbstractClass, IInterface
{
    [Column(nameof(IInterface.Order))]
    public int Order { get; set; }
}

public class SecondImplementation : AbstractClass, IInterface
{
    [Column(nameof(IInterface.Order))]
    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

and other implementations, but they don't have `Order` property.

```
public class MyContext
{
    public DbSet<AbstractClass> AbstratClass { get; set; }
}
```

I cannot put property `Order` in `AbstractClass`,cause other logic and because other implementations don't have the property, and I try these solution with `ColumnAttribute` to map it in one column.

But when I try these query, it throws an exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'The specified type member 'Order' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.'

The query:

```
myContext.AbstractClass
         .OfType<FirstImplementation>()
         .Concat<IInterface>(myContext.AbstractClass
                                      .OfType<SecondImplementation>())
         .Max(x => x.Order);
```

The goal should be to execute `Max` with `IQueryable<T>`

I tried some solutions in stackoverflow but didn't work

EDIT:
Working query:

`myContext.AbstractClass.OfType<FirstImplementation>().Max(x => x.Order)`

or

`myContext.AbstractClass.OfType<FirstImplementation>().AsQueryable<IInterface>().Max(x => x.Order)`

Exception throw when I `Concat` IQueryable

Comment: Million posts? Are you serious?

Comment: Your issue seems to be that you think a relational DB can somehow do inheritance when it cannot.  If you need to separate the first and second implementations then you'll need separate tables and thus separate DbSets for both.

Comment: @juharr _"you think a relational DB can somehow do inheritance when it cannot"_ - that's a misrepresentation. Anyway, [EF Core _does_ support a variety of class-hierarchy-to-table mapping strategies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance) - though I do agree that it's a very bad idea to use any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Your context only contains a `DbSet` of `AbstractClass`, but not of `FirstImplementation`. According to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20056) `OfType<DerivedType>` only works with entity framework, if `DerivedType` is known to the `DbContext` (see first comment of smitpatel).

Comment: I'll try later separate `DbSet` too. However the problem is with `Max` method, not with `OfType` because if I run these query: `myContext.AbstractClass.OfType<FirstImplementation>().Max(x => x.Order)`, these query works and returns result. Only after a `Concat` throw an exception

Comment: Also these query works: `myContext.AbstractClass.OfType<FirstImplementation>().AsQueryable<IInterface>().Max(x => x.Order)`
So I don't understand what is the problem